# How to update Angular + Firebase project to Support Artifact Registry for Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After making a minor update to a Firebase Function in my Angular project, I tried to deploy the function which failed. The error referred to enabling the Artifact Registry in the Google Cloud. I search and read the docs and posts and getting started tutorials, but no one mentions this step to be able to use Firebase Functions.

> Cloud Functions uses Artifact Registry to store function docker
> images. Artifact Registry API is not enabled in your project. To
> enable the API, visit...

The official documentation about Transitioning from Container Registry to Artifact Registry is way complicated. I do not know about Docker images and repositories. I simply want to deploy my cloud functions from an Angular project using Firebase. Here is the article:
https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr

So is Artifact Registry a new requirement for Firebase Functions in 2022? And if so, what is the correct way to add, migrate, and configure the API in an existing project?

In the Google Cloud Console, I am prompted to "Try Artifact Registry." After enabling a task appears: "Create gcr.io repositories in Artifact Registry?" with a Create button to click. Clicking gives me options to select which host names and container images along with commands to run. I have no idea how or if this applies to Firebase Functions specifically -  I do not use Google Cloud CLI directly. Thanks for helping to explain how to configure it properly so Firebase Functions works like before :)

Comment: Update - After enabling Artifact Registry and clicking to Create gcr.io repositories, I get this prompt: 
All "*gcr.io" traffic is currently routed to Container Registry. Route to Artifact Registry after copying any images you need from Container Registry.

So I need to manually copy and route and update permissions? However my Container Registry is empty. There is nothing to migrate, so what traffic is being re-routed to handle Cloud Functions?